# How to fix Error 403 Forbidden in Wordpress from CPANEL?

Tags: wordpress

How do you fix an error from CPANEL when the main domain is "Forbidden"?

How do you fix an error from CPANEL when the main domain is "Forbidden"? What is the most appropriate permission for **public_html** to be safer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to your account in hosting provider,
- Manage your hosting
- Open `CPANEL`
- Select `Files`  => `File manager`
- Right click `public_html`
- Select `Change permissions`
- Do this: 
  [image]
- Click `Change Permissions`
  `750 = User:rwx Group:r-x World:---`

---

Other sub folder like `wp-content`, `wp-includes`, etc 
Change to 755
Like:
[image]

Any file in folder `public_html` set to: 644
[image]

Others leave it as is